# Grails : UrlMapping tests failing : "did not match any mappings"

Tags: grails

I'm studying Grails framework and developing an application.

At the moment I have a main application which has severals plugins.

So the hierarchy is like that :

- MyMainApp

  - MyFirstPlugin
  - MySecondPlugin
  - ...

I would like to write UrlMappings tests for my plugins. I wrote the doc and I'm probably missing something but I can't pass those f****** tests. I always catch the error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: url '/bar' did not match any mappings

Here is my FooUrlMappings class

```
class FooUrlMappings {
    static mappings = {

        "/bar/"(controller: 'foo', action: 'show')
    }
}
```

Note that my FooUrlMappings class is in the default package in /conf directory.

Now the code of my controller FooController :

```
package be.arexo.ehr.employee.rest
```

import be.arexo.ehr.employee.Employee
import grails.converters.JSON

```
class FooController {

    // GET /bar/
    def show() {
        def result = Bar.list()

        render result as JSON
    }
}
```

So now, my test class :

```
import com.example.FooController
import grails.test.mixin.Mock
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.web.UrlMappingsUnitTestMixin

@TestFor(FooUrlMappings)
@Mock(FooController)
class FooUrlMappingsTests {

    void testBarShow(){
        assertForwardUrlMapping("/bar/", controller : "foo", action : "show")
    }
}
```

My test is also in the default package in the test/integration directory.

So I think that I did what is said in the documentation. If I try to run this test I will get :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: url '/bar' did not match any mappings

Where is my mistake ? Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Can you add the url that you are calling for?

Comment: I just want to pass this test :
assertForwardUrlMapping("/bar/", controller : "foo", action : "show")

Comment: the only thing that I can think of its that maybe you should scape the second / like "/bar\/"

Comment: Already tried, it didn't work.

Comment: Where is your fooController? I only see RestEmployeeController. Is that a typo?

Comment: I'd get rid of the second slash, both in the urlMapping and in the test. Like this: "/bar"(controller: 'foo', action: 'show') -  assertForwardUrlMapping("/bar", controller : "foo", action : "show")

Comment: I've just tried it , didn't work again...

Answer (score 0):

You should run URL mappings tests as unit tests, not as integration tests. This will solve your problem.

> @TestFor(FooUrlMappings)

Note that the TestFor annotation can only be used in unit tests.

> My test is also in the default package in the test/integration
>   directory.

Move your test to the test/unit/ directory.